# DashClock Extension for Android

Tags: app, android, widget, extension

[image: Feature Graphic]

### About

Displays the user's reputation on the Android lock screen as an extension of the popular [**DashClock widget**](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock). It can be switched between displaying the **total** reputation score and **today's** reputation score. In the expanded view of DashClock, the last reputation changes are displayed, for example:

> **+10** — How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here
>   **+25** — DashClock Extension for Android

In addition to the use as a lock screen widget, DashClock can as well be used as a regular home screen widget.

The extension is applicable for all sites in the Stack Exchange network and only needs the User ID.

### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot: DashClock expanded view]
[image: Screenshot: DashClock Extensions]

### Download

The extension can be downloaded from the Google Play Store. It requires the [**DashClock widget**](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock) by Roman Nurik.

[image: Get it on Google Play]

#### Platform

**Android 4.2+** – unfortunately, older versions of the platform can not be supported as long as DashClock itself is only available for 4.2 and above.

#### Setup

1. After you downloaded and installed **DashClock** and **Stack DashClock Extension**, add the DashClock widget to your lock screen and/or home screen.
2. Open DashClock's settings, navigate to section ***Extensions*** and click ***+ Add another extension***.
3. Select ***Stack Exchange***
4. Enter site and user ID and you're done!

Comment: The google play link seems to be broken.